# Couldn't find Authorization with 'id'=0 using each_with_index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, each, rails-4-2-1

I have this error and this is my code:

```
 params[:authorization][:contract_ids].each_with_index do |index, id|
      Authorization.find(id).update_column(value_solve: params[:authorization][:value_solve])
    end
```

This started with 0, and Authorization have id 1 and forward. How solve this? I tried many things but nothing don't worked =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer this is:

```
      auth_params = params[:authorization]
auth_params[:contract_number].zip(auth_params[:value_solve].reject(&:blank?)).each do |contract_number, value_solve|
          Authorization.where(contract_number: contract_number).update_all(value_solve: value_solve, situation: 2)
      end
```

:D

Answer (score 0):

I see, you are not even using `index`, just go straight with `.each` looping.

Try this one:

```
 params[:authorization][:contract_ids].each do |id|
      Authorization.find(id).update_column(value_solve: params[:authorization][:value_solve])
 end
```

Comment: don't solve... =/ other error: Couldn't find Authorization with 'id'=010101 << this is my contract_number